# How to set the value of an html input field in java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have two files.
An .html that contains a `<input type="text">` and a .java that contains java methods.
In a java method I need to set the value of that html input.
What is the code to do that?

Here is the code I have.

View

```
<form action="personform" method="post" th:object="${personBind}">
<input type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}">
<input type="text" name="year" th:field="*{year}">
```

Spring MVC Controller

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Person.html");
modelAndView.addObject("personBind", person);
return modelAndView;
```

The value in the name field comes from the person object in the modelAndView.
That works fine.
But the value for the year field is not in the person object.
I want to set the value in the year field coming from a different source.
What code should I write to set the value in the year field?

Comment: I recommend read the next link: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

Comment: @BryanST25 This is a good base article. But didn't find an answer for the specific thing I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some tests.

This is how the code I posted on the question needs to be updated.

View

```
<form action="personform" method="post" th:object="${personBind}">
<input type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}">
<input type="text" name="year" th:value="${yearBind}">
```

Controller

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Person.html");
modelAndView.addObject("personBind", person);
modelAndView.addObject("yearBind", "2020");
return modelAndView;
```

Note it's a th:value for the year instead of a th:field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question completely you want the year field to be populated from data from a different object. Perhaps try implementing a Data Transfer Object to back the form instead of the actual object you're trying to modify. Something like this:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Year year;


    public Person() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Year getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Year year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}


public class PersonDTO {

    private String name;
    private String year;

    public PersonDTO() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(name);
        person.setYear(Year.parse(year));
        return person;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller has something like this

```
PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO();
// manipulate object as needed, setters ect.

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Person.html");
modelAndView.addObject("personDto", dto);
return modelAndView;
```

And your thymeleaf view looks something like this

```
<form action="personform" method="post" th:object="${personDto}">
<input type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}">
<input type="text" name="year" th:field="*{year}">
```

What this does is it decouples the Person object from the form so that if the year data is coming from somewhere else you can modify the DTO to facilitate that then in your `@PostMapping` where you process the form data, save it ect. you can call `personDto.getPerson()` and save the `Person` object or do what ever you were planning to do.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. That's exactly what I need to do. Your solution would work. I just think it's a lot of coding and extra classes and objects to deal with. Isn't there something simpler? For instance, in asp.net C# you can achive that simply by writing one line of code: TextBoxYear.Text = "2020". That's all. Java doen't have something similar?

Comment: Where exactly is the data coming from? Do you want to year field to be automatically populated with the current year? There are ways to call methods in a thymeleaf view but it really doesn't work well if the method requires arguments

Comment: No, the year field here is just an example. So I'm not looking to populate the year field with the current year. In my real app it's another field to be populated with another content. So what I'm trying to understand is what is the simplest way populate an html input field with a simple string from the java code. If it can be done without the need to create a class and an object. If there's something simple like the asp.net example I gave. TextBoxName.Text = "John"; TextBoxWhatever.Text = "whatever".

Comment: I know one way to bind a list of strings without the need for a class and object: List<String> msg; msg.add("msg 1"); msg.add("msg 2"); modelAndView.addObject("msg", msg). For the view: <div th:each = "m : ${msg}"><span th:text = "${m}"></span></div>. Do you know how to change that code to bind one single string instead of a whole list? Want to have a single string in the controller and remove the iteration from the view.

Comment: I found out how to do it based on this last example I sent you. I posted it as an answer. But your DTO example was very nice. Although requiring more code, it is a good solution as well. I tried to mark your answer as useful but stackoverflow says the vote will be computed but not publicly displayed because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the model object you want to populate in form in the Controller class using

```
    Student s = new Student("job","tyson");
    model.addAttribute("student",s);
```

Now you can use the same object value in the form by using form tags

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>

<title>form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student">'
    
    First Name : <form:input path="firstName" />
    
    <input type="submit">

    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

The modelAttribute should match the model attribute passed to jsp by the controller, spring in the background will populate the form input by calling respective getter methods. so FirstName input field will be populated with student.getFirstName(), if it is null the input field will be blank.

Comment: I'm using thymeleaf in the html. And what is the code in the java method?

Comment: I'm already binding an object to the form just like you mentioned.
But in this specific field I want to bind a value that is not available in that object.
So needs to be a separate binding.

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question, that will make it easy to understand what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: done. I edited the question adding the code.